Construction of a function subject to conditions
Is it possible to construct $f \in H(B(0,1))$ such that $f(1/n) = z_n$, where:

$z_n = (-1)^n$
$z_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$
$z_n = 0$ if $n$ is even and $z_n = \frac{1}{n}$ when $n$ is odd?

Is the following solution correct?

$f(z)$ cannot be holomorphic at $0$
$f(z) = 1/(1+z)$
For the subsequence $z_{2n}$ $f(z)$ has a cluster point at $0$ so $f = 0 $ but $f$ is not constant.


You are right, yes.
